# Two equal charges accelerating parallel to each other

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

Let's say constant acceleration for simplicity.

Ignore possible logistic concerns, such as what is accelerating them or how they stay in path. Lets just assume they are in a conduit made of a solid material with same electromagnetic properties as free space, and the same solid material pushes them with constant acceleration.

What do I need to know to understand what would happen?

I am familiar with with maxwell's equations but I do not really see how I would apply them. Do I need to know some other equations etc.? It's okay if an analytic solution is not possible, i'd also like a method which can be implemented numerically.

This is different from the other question because in this question they are accelerated.

Comment: It is perfectly legit question in SR. Move to the accelerated frame of reference where they both at rest (or at least their center of mass/charge). Solve whatever you want to solve, and then make the transformation back to your original coordinates.

Comment: But I don't know special relativity. I know electromagnetism. Also isn't accelerating reference frames the topic of general relativity?

Comment: Try to use the field transformation equations, it should work.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity

Maxwell equations are already relativistic, thus in proper (tensorial) use should be invariant under coordinate transformation.

Comment: @grdgfgr : general relativity is theory of gravity.In some cases SR can handle acceleration.

Comment: @Alexander I know to use the $\nabla$ maxwell equations, do I need to get even more tensorial?